# Can someone identify the era, nationality, crew and type of boat from this albumen photo?

Tags: uniform

Can someone identify the era, nationality, crew and type of boat from this albumen photo? Note small cannon on far left. Thanks

[image]

We can add few more close-ups if necessary.

Comment: Any more information you can supply about this photograph?

Comment: If this is in an album, the other photos on the page may also provide context.  If it is a loose photo, are there any markings on the back?

Comment: Looks like a (large) yacht to me, probably much like the twin masted vessel immediately astern. The 'cannon' is probably a saluting/signalling gun. Certainly, the seated ladies and the gentleman lying on the deck at the rear suggest that this is a civilian vessel.

Comment: The ribbons on the hats usually had the ship name on them. It's albumen, so 1850-1900, the clothing style strongly suggests 1860-1880. The hats with the round low brim is probably the primary defining feature of the uniforms. There are several people with that same hat, so probably not just one man's preference.

Comment: The launch/lifeboat in davits suggests a passenger vessel.

Comment: In reply to comments so far: photo is stand-alone, not part of album and there are no markings on the back. Thanks to all with your thoughts.

Comment: Looks like a two masted vessel, similar to the one behind it in the photo.  The clothing & hair styles are compatible with 1890-1910, though possibly older. Note the lack of beards.